# 5 questions from a newbie about token2022

Tags: solana-program, solana-cli, spl-token-program, token-2022, spl-token-cli

I created a token2022 with Spl token cli (windows)

can i add a logo to this

How should I technically proceed to add it to any exchange?

Transaction History

"Executable: No "

" Current Supply  0 "

is this normal

thank you.

Comment: you should mint a few tokens for example 100, then go to some dex (orca, raidyum or fluxbeam) find the button that is something like "add liquidity" or "create liquidity pool" and there you have to supply 100 of your minted tokens and some SOL so your pair would eventually be yourtoken/SOL. You will get back some lp tokens with which you can do "remove liquidity" or also known as "rug pull"